# I can't get HDRI to work right with EEVEE

Tags: eevee-render-engine, hdri

I've been following some tutorials where they use HDRI to light a scene in EEVEE.  For some reason it is not working when I do it.  I don't get it.  What am I doing wrong with HDRI in EEVEE ?  In Cycles, no problem, but in EEVEE its as if the HDRI is not lighting my scene.  I'm not new to Blender, I know how nodes work etc... but this has me going around in circles getting nowhere.  I've attached 2 screen grabs to illustrate.  The scene is very simple, all I do is switch between Cycles and EEVEE.  As you can see, in EEVEE the plane and the object are just blue.
[image: Cycles vs EEVEE HDRI]

Comment: Can you add screenshots of your material nodes?

Comment: Can we see the file?  There's something weird going on here, but it probably doesn't have anything to do with your HDRI, but with your curve object and its materials.

Comment: I can't give an exact solution, but I thought i'd point out something interesting - the ground in EEVEE isn't rendering at all. For one of us to find an actual solution though, like Nathan said, we would need to see the file.

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing anything wrong. Eevee is not a ray tracer like cycles, so it will not produce the same results with an hdri. The best workaround to this is to try and fake the cycles render by switching between it and eevee using lamps to try and match it.

Answer (score 0):

What about enabling those :

- Screen space reflections
- Bloom

Also, some material characteristics may not be compatible at the moment for eevee. That's why some advanced shaders have a version tweaked for eevee.

Is your "metal" object a simple metal (hence, the metal slide bar set to 1) ?